# Both model classes having belongs_to to each other in Rails/ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, orm, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a versioning mechanism for a Lesson model:

```
class Lesson < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :lesson_version_id, :number
  belongs_to :lesson_version
end

class LessonVersion < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :lesson_id, :version
  belongs_to :lesson
end
```

There's a 1-many relationship between `Lesson` and `LessonVersion`.  I've modeled that by having `belongs_to :lesson` in the `LessonVersion` class.  For now, I won't deal with the `has_many :lesson_versions` in the Lesson class part of that relationship.

Secondly, I also need to know the latest version for each lesson to be able to immediately pull it up. So in the `Lesson` model I need a reference to a `LessonVersion`. I guess this is a 1-1 type relationship.

Does this make sense to model it this way?  Will I get in trouble having a `belongs_to` in each class to each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating another relationship, I would use a scope on `LessonVersion`.

```
class Lesson < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :number
  has_many :lesson_versions

  def most_recent_version
    lesson_versions.most_recent.first
  end
end

class LessonVersion < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :lesson_id, :version
  belongs_to :lesson
  scope :recent, order("created_at DESC")
end
```

Also, you might prefer to order by `"version DESC"` if version is an integer that increases with each new version.

**EDIT**: After reading your comment, I have two suggestions.

**Suggestion 1**

Use my solution above, but with `"version DESC"` for the sort, and when you want to revert to an older version, instead duplicate it and make it the newest version. Then you have a history of all edits and don't need

As for the order in the query, if you add a compound index on `version` and `lesson_id` in the database this will be a trivial operation. Also, calling `#first` on a scope is efficient, it will query with `LIMIT 1` and only instantiate the record you care about. And the result of the query is automatically cached if you need to use this method multiple times in the same request.

**Suggestion 2**

Set up a belongs_to on Lesson, but name it :current_version so as to prevent confusion.

```
class Lesson < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :number, :current_version_id
  has_many :lesson_versions
  belongs_to :current_version, :class_name => "LessonVersion"
end

class LessonVersion < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :lesson_id, :version
  belongs_to :lesson
  scope :recent, order("created_at DESC")
end
```

Comment: Thank you for this, yes I think this will work. But to me this is pretty ugly. Every request for the lesson_version of a lesson will have to do that order operation (and there will be a lot of these requests). I also don't have the freedom then to maybe move the current lesson version to a previous version.

Comment: I like your 2nd suggestion.  I'm not really worried about the confusing naming, it's not confusing to me to have lesson.lesson_version mean the current version.  But yours is more clear.  So does it matter?  Would I run into trouble with having it my original way?

Comment: The only trouble you would run into would be if another developer joins your project. When they see an association called lesson_version, then they might expect by Rails convention that it's the inverse of the belongs_to :lesson and that it's a has_one relationship. They would have to go into the model code to see that it actually has this other meaning which is non-standard.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is has_and_belongs_to_many, which pecifies a many-to-many relationship with another class.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_and_belongs_to_many

Comment: But it's not a many to many relationship, it's 2 different relationships. It should be implemented as a foreign key in each table to each other. ActiveRecord's `has_and_belongs_to_many` creates an unnecessary (in my case) join table.